# HTML email formatting doens't show correct in outlook 2000,2002/xp, 2003

Tags: html, email

I have the following email code:

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
<!--[if gte mso 7]><TABLE border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width=600 height=600 style="margin:0px;padding:0px;max-width:600px;max-height:600px;width:600px;height:600px;">
<TR>
<TD width=364 height=503 style="margin:0px;padding:0px;max-width:364px;max-height:503px;width:364px;height:503px;">
<a href="https://www.ortho.nl/boeken/het-gouden-boekje-voor-het-hart?source=fmvemail">
<img align="left" width=364 height=503 style="margin:0px;padding:0px;max-width:364px;max-height:503px;width:364px;height:503px;" border=0 src="https://www.ortho.nl/css/image.php?file=nb/20121129ortho2.png&fmvopen=yes" /></a>
</TD>
<TD rowspan=2  width=236 height=600 style="margin:0px;padding:0px;max-width:236px;max-height:600px;width:236px;height:600px;">
<a href="https://www.ortho.nl/boeken/het-gouden-boekje-voor-de-gezondheid?source=fmvemail">
<img align="right" border=0 width=236 height=600 style="margin:0px;padding:0px;max-width:236px;max-height:600px;width:236px;height:600px;" src="https://www.ortho.nl/css/image.php?file=nb/20121129ortho3.png&fmvopen=yes" /></a>
</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD width=364 height=97 style="margin:0px;padding:0px;max-width:364px;max-height:97px;width:364px;height:97px;">
<a href="http://www.gezondeboeken.nl?source=fmvemail"><img width=364 height=97 align="left" style="margin:0px;padding:0px;max-width:364px;max-height:97px;width:364px;height:97px;" border=0 src="https://www.ortho.nl/css/image.php?file=nb/20121129ortho1.png&fmvopen=yes" /></a>
</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gte mso 7]>
<script type="text/javascript">/*
<![endif]-->
<div style="border:1px solid black;width:600px;height:600px;max-width:600px;max-height:600px">
<a href="https://www.ortho.nl/boeken/het-gouden-boekje-voor-het-hart?source=fmvemail">
<img align=left width=364 height=503 style="margin:0px;padding:0px;max-width:364px;max-height:503px;width:364px;height:503px;" border=0 src="https://www.ortho.nl/css/image.php?file=nb/20121129ortho2.png&fmvopen=yes"></a>

<a href="http://www.gezondeboeken.nl?source=fmvmail">
<img width=364 height=97 align=left style="margin:0px;padding:0px;max-width:364px;max-height:97px;width:364px;height:97px;" border=0 src="https://www.ortho.nl/css/image.php?file=nb/20121129ortho1.png&fmvopen=yes"></a>

<a href="https://www.ortho.nl/boeken/het-gouden-boekje-voor-de-gezondheid?source=fmvemail">
<img border=0 align=top width=236 height=600 style="margin:0px;padding:0px;max-width:236px;max-height:600px;width:236px;height:600px;" src="https://www.ortho.nl/css/image.php?file=nb/20121129ortho3.png&fmvopen=yes"></a>
<!--[if gte mso 7]>
*/</script>
<![endif]-->
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

but it will simply not render like a proper table in outlook 2000 - 2003. I've tried a lot of things to make it work, but it simply won't show up properly in those clients when I test it with [litmus.com](http://www.litmus.com)

Does anyone know  a trick to get the tables working in those clients? Or is there a  trick I can utilise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better to Use Everything in Tables for all Email Vendors. Outlook will not support Div tags it will support only old Tables Format.

Comment: only problem is whilst in outlook it looks great in other clients it gets skewed.